# PHP Call a user function with its own result if isset

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm trying to actually loop a function with a different function parameter each time which is obtained by the function itself;

Im using a variable `$login_name` as function parameter which was submitted by a form. So I want to change this parameter by the function itself. absurd? is there any alternative?

Here's my function

```
$login_name = "U00001";
while (!isset($end)) {
    function getcount($login_name) {
        $get_node = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM b_userbase WHERE login_name='$login_name'");
        while ($row_node = mysql_fetch_array($get_node)) {
            $node = $row_node["user_node"];
            $placement = $row_node["user_placement"];
        }
        $current_count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM f_user_matching WHERE u_m_mem='$placement'");
        while ($get_count = mysql_fetch_array($current_count)) {
            $get_left_current = $get_count["u_m_left_current"];
            $get_left_total = $get_count["u_m_left_total"];
            $get_right_current = $get_count["u_m_right_current"];
            $get_right_total = $get_count["u_m_right_total"];
            $update_left_current = $get_left_current + 1;
            $update_right_current = $get_right_current + 1;
            $update_left_total = $get_left_total + 1;
            $update_right_total = $get_right_total + 1;
        }
        if ($node == "L") {
            $increase_qry = mysql_query("UPDATE f_user_matching 
                                            SET u_m_left_current= '{$update_left_current}',
                                                u_m_left_total ='{$update_left_total}'
                                            WHERE u_m_mem ='{$placement}' ");
        }
        if ($node == "R") {
            $increase_qry = mysql_query("UPDATE f_user_matching 
                                            SET u_m_right_current= '{$update_right_current}',
                                                u_m_right_total ='{$update_right_total}'
                                            WHERE u_m_mem ='{$placement}' ");
        }
        $login_name = $placement;
        if ($login_name == "IM000001") {
            $end = 1;
        } else {
            $login_name = $placement;
        }
        global $login_name;
    }
    $count = getcount($login_name);
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete and concise–just enough to illustrate the issue and stand on its own, but no more. The extraneous code is a distraction. The old mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use PDO or the mysqli extension, both of which support prepared statements. Prepared statement parameters aren't vulnerable to injection. Prepared statements themselves are more performant with repeated queries because the statement only needs to be parsed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand what you ar doing, so you might be trying to do something different that I do not know about, but if what you need is an **recursive function** then this is not the way. You dont define the function inside a while-loop, the function should be defined as a normal function, but in can call itself whit a different result.

This is how your function would be as recursive.
**This is not tested code**

```
    <?php

 $login_name = "U00001";
 $count = getcount($login_name);

 function getcount($login_name) {
        $get_node = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM b_userbase WHERE login_name='$login_name'");
        while ($row_node = mysql_fetch_array($get_node)) {
            $node = $row_node["user_node"];
            $placement = $row_node["user_placement"];
        }
        $current_count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM f_user_matching WHERE u_m_mem='$placement'");
        while ($get_count = mysql_fetch_array($current_count)) {
            $get_left_current = $get_count["u_m_left_current"];
            $get_left_total = $get_count["u_m_left_total"];
            $get_right_current = $get_count["u_m_right_current"];
            $get_right_total = $get_count["u_m_right_total"];
            $update_left_current = $get_left_current + 1;
            $update_right_current = $get_right_current + 1;
            $update_left_total = $get_left_total + 1;
            $update_right_total = $get_right_total + 1;
        }
        if ($node == "L") {
            $increase_qry = mysql_query("UPDATE f_user_matching 
                                            SET u_m_left_current= '{$update_left_current}',
                                                u_m_left_total ='{$update_left_total}'
                                            WHERE u_m_mem ='{$placement}' ");
        }
        if ($node == "R") {
            $increase_qry = mysql_query("UPDATE f_user_matching 
                                            SET u_m_right_current= '{$update_right_current}',
                                                u_m_right_total ='{$update_right_total}'
                                            WHERE u_m_mem ='{$placement}' ");
        }
        $login_name = $placement;
        if ($login_name != "IM000001") {
            $login_name = $placement;
            $count = getcount($login_name);
        }
        global $login_name; // Dont know why you want this one?

    }

    ?>
```

Dont know why you have *global $login_name;* at the end. Do you want the function to return something or just perform the **UPDATE** in the database?

Comment: I dont use the (!isset($end)), I just dont call the function anymore. I therefore dont need the line: $end = 1;

Comment: Thanks a lottt for the help! I was missing some basics :) This works and a perfect answer. U saved my day. Btw, cant find a way to vote you up (req 15 reputation).

Comment: Ya I don't need the global flag anymore either. It was just a try to update the $login_name variable globally. - total wrong approach.

Comment: That is great :) Discovering the need for recursive functions without know about this process shows you have a talent for algorithms :)